# datagrid OnMouseLeftButtonDown detect click in outside grid rows area

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, wpfdatagrid

I have a WPF datagrid where in certain rows (say 30) are added and certain area in grid below these rows is blank. I have to detect inside function OnMouseLeftButtonDown whether click was on row's area or in blank area.

Appreciate any help

Comment: code taka saheb tumhi try kelela

Comment: private void DataGrid_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)  gets call on left click at any point of grid...now if we have certain rows added to grid and some area left blank....click on rows vs click in blank area  ...need to  identify

Answer (score 0):

If you use `DataGrid_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)`, It's means when you click on any area of the grid (Row Areas and Empty Area).

If you need to click on the row I think Best thing is 
Datagrid Selection Change is Better.

```
DataGrid_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
```